# Alternative to printf "%A"

Tags: f#, printf

Is there another way to get the value printed by the `%A` specifier (for DUs particularly)? `printf` is too slow for my current use.

Comment: Define slow. Why does printing to the console have to be fast?

Comment: I'd suggest manually implementing the `.ToString` method. I think `printf "%A"` is slow because it uses reflection.

Comment: @RamonSnir: That's what I've done...just wondering if there's an alternative I'm not aware of.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: `ToString` is equivalent to `%O`, not `%A`.

Comment: @leppie: I was using `printf` to refer to the family of functions. I'm actually using `sprintf`, which uses the same internal function, to format diagnostic messages...and yes, it needs to be fast.

Comment: @Daniel: If available, `fprintf` would be faster due to elimination of string copying. (Sorry I dont know F# well)

Comment: @leppie: Ramon's right that the biggest hit to performance is reflection. I thought there might be a function somewhere in the BCL for this. Obviously the debugger gets it from somewhere...but it may be internal.

Comment: The debugger also gets it using reflection (so still slow). Don Syme had a blog post about how to give formatting to the VS debugger, I doubt it'll help, but you should try to find it.

Comment: Your source (printf.fs) Have you tried to see?
"%A" is certainly doing various.
 I think that If you can't replace by ToString () , you can't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is apparently no. Overriding `ToString` seems to be the preferred alternative.